# Encoding specified in XML declaration is incorrect

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, xml-parsing, elementtree

I'm trying to access the XML elements using ElementTree in Python 3.7. XML entry tag in the file `my_file.xml` is of the format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
```

When I try to parse the XML using the below method,

```
>>import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
>>file_content = ET.parse('my_file.xml')
```

I keep getting the error as:

```
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: encoding specified in XML declaration is incorrect
```

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does ElementTree reject UTF-16 XML declarations with "encoding incorrect"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24045892/why-does-elementtree-reject-utf-16-xml-declarations-with-encoding-incorrect)

Comment: Oh yes, it does.