# Anyway to parse a UTF-16 XML file into an instance of ElementTree?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree, utf-16

I am trying to parse a XML file into python using the ElementTree class, which also means that I want to make it into a ElementTree instance. I tried using the "parse" method of the ElementTree class, but it gives the following error:

```
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: encoding specified in XML declaration is incorrect: line 1, column 30
```

When investigating further, it is because it doesn't like the fact that the inputted XML file is encoded in UTF-16 rather than UTF-8.

Any way to parse this XML and make it into a `ElementTree` instance?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24045892/407651

Comment: So the file is UTF-16, but claims to be UTF-8?